# Error Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, point

I code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void nhap(int **s, int line, int column)
{
int x;
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
for(int i=0; i<line; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
    {
        x=rand()%10+0;
        *(*(s+i)+j)=x;
    }

}

void xuat(int **s, int line, int column)
{
for(int i=0; i<line; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
        printf("%3d",s[i][j]);
}
}

int main()
{
int line,column;
printf("\nLine: "); scanf("%d",&line);
printf("\nColumn: "); scanf("%d",&column);

int **s=new int*[line];
for(int i=0; i<line; i++)
    s[i]=new int[column];

nhap(s,line,column);
xuat(s,line,column);

getch();
for(int i=0; i<line; i++)
    delete[] (s+i);
delete[] s;
}
```

Error: Debug Assertion Failed! 
Exspression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID.
For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

Comment: Running fine on my PC.. Windows + Visual Studio 10

Comment: You are inconsistent, `*(*(s+i)+j)` and `s[i][j]`. You should stick to the later, it's simpler to use.

Comment: Oh no. It's no error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete [] (s+i);` is your error. For clarity you should probably just stick to regular array syntax. The `*(s+i)` stuff is equivalent, but harder to read/understand. So I'd use `delete [] s[i]`.